# app module for permissions assignment on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm developing and application with ruby on rails . i have the following models : user, role, option, permission. Depending on the Role of an User i want the menu of the application to display certain options. So an USER  has one ROLE, one ROLE has one or many OPTIONS (availables in the menu),one OPTION can be assigned to many Roles . that's why i created a join table called PERMISSION which has rol_id , option_id and status.

SO, in the app, i want to be able to create a new role and check from a list the options this Role can have. But i don't know how to do a form that let me handle all this information and assign the role_id and the option_id the join table needs.

Answer (score 0):

**"Best" Solution:**

Code it yourself, you should definitely become more familiar with ActiveRecord and be comfortable utilizing relationship tables and the roles one may have, along with writing helper functions like "is_an_admin?" or "is_a_moderator?"

You should also be comfortable with the routes and controllers for adding new users and checking permissions for can POST / UPDATE / PATCH / DELETE entries on your roles database.

Some db like "roles" where you store a user_id and role_level (1 is super_admin, 2 admin, or 3 moderator etc etc) and a user "has_one :role" association?

So my honest recommendation would be to learn it properly, here's some resources:

- [CULTTT Implementing Roles and Permissions](http://culttt.com/2016/01/20/implementing-roles-and-permissions-in-ruby-on-rails/)
- [Association Basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

**Easiest Solution**

Use a gem, some options:

- rolify (https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify)
- CanCanCan (https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan)
- Pundit (https://github.com/elabs/pundit)